# print strings from list

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement

I am intended to construct a list of strings from list of numbers. For example, the given list is

```
list=[1,2,5,25,6]
```

Desired output:

```
['Odd', 'Even', Odd, 'multiples of 5 and odd', 'multiples of 2 and even']
```

My work so far:

```
list=[]
for num in numbers:
        if num % 2:
            list.append('Odd')
            if not num % 5:
               list.append('multiples of 5 and odd')
            else:
               if not num % 5:
                 list.append('multiples of 2 and even')
               else: 
                 list.append('even')
print(list)
```

It printed the list but in a wrong way. I was wondering you if you could review my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: there are many things to comment here but to begin with, note that you are appending `"odd"` before doing any further checks. You do not want that; you should append once all checks are done.

Comment: are you sure your `if` condition is right?`if not num % 5` I think it should be other way around without not?

Comment: Is the indentation in your question the same as in your code? Because as it stands the path leading to `even` is not the `else` to `if num % 2`

Comment: NEVER EVER USE BUILTINS (`list`) AS VARIABLE NAMES, you will thank me later

Comment: There is no `else` for your `if num % 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
l = []
for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        # Even numbers
        # Every even number is a multiple of 2 except number 0
        if num == 0:
            l.append('Even')
        else:
            l.append('Multiples of 2 and even')
    else:
        # Odd numbers
        if num % 5 == 0:
            l.append('Multiples of 5 and odd')
        else:
            l.append('Odd')
print(l)
```

Comment: @Barsal you can mark it as the answer and upvote it if it was useful as a way to thank other users contribution